# Syntax for color name

Tags: git

What is the syntax for the `name` to be used in `git config --get-color name`?

I tried the following to find out the built-in default color for `[status] added` but all returned nothing:

```
git config --get-color status.added
git config --get-color color.status.added
git config --get-color color.added
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is: (see [`git config color.status.<slot>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-colorstatusltslotgt))

```
git config --get-color color.status.added
```

But if it returns nothing, that simply means it uses the default color for that slot.

See "[Colors in Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_colors_in_git)".

The default colors are defined in [`wt-status.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/69d71ec4433d21f464d83b529432856da2387bba/wt-status.c#L24-L34):

```
static char default_wt_status_colors[][COLOR_MAXLEN] = {
    GIT_COLOR_NORMAL, /* WT_STATUS_HEADER */
    GIT_COLOR_GREEN,  /* WT_STATUS_UPDATED */
    GIT_COLOR_RED,    /* WT_STATUS_CHANGED */
    GIT_COLOR_RED,    /* WT_STATUS_UNTRACKED */
    GIT_COLOR_RED,    /* WT_STATUS_NOBRANCH */
    GIT_COLOR_RED,    /* WT_STATUS_UNMERGED */
    GIT_COLOR_GREEN,  /* WT_STATUS_LOCAL_BRANCH */
    GIT_COLOR_RED,    /* WT_STATUS_REMOTE_BRANCH */
    GIT_COLOR_NIL,    /* WT_STATUS_ONBRANCH */
};
```

Comment: When do changes in the `config` file take effect?  Upon every invocation of the `git` command?  Or is there a reload command somewhere?

Comment: @OldGeezer if you specify a color in a config file (see `git config -l --show-origin`), then every Git command would take it into account.

Comment: I am getting an odd behavior. `git config -l` shows `color.status.added=red black bold`, but `git config --get-color color.status.added` still returns empty.  `git status` displays red though for added files.

Comment: @OldGeezer That is why I mentioned `git config -l --show-origin`: you will see in which config file this is defined, which can matter.

Comment: The color line is in `C:\ProgramData\Git/config`.  It's the file that I added the line manually. Does `git config --get-color` not read from this file?

Comment: @OldGeezer That seems to be the system config. If status is displayed red on black background, then it is taken into account.